# Precompilation in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps, pre-compilation

As in older versions of rails, in production, we used to precompile our assets first so that performance can be better while serving assets from public. But in rails 7, as default configuration says that you should use all your css , fonts, and custom js files from asset pipeline and ecternal js libraries using importmaps, then what is the precompilation process of rails 7 in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing changed. Asset pipeline aka `sprockets` or `propshaft` are used in development to serve any local assets, including `import-maps`. When you make changes, assets are **compiled** on the fly and new assets are served when you refresh the page. This process takes time, memory, and cpu cycles - something you don't want to waste in production.

Solution is to compile everything ahead of time - **precompile**. Everything goes into `public/assets` directory. Then web server, like `nginx`, is configured to serve any requests to `/assets/*` from `public/assets/*`. This way assets are served fast and your app server doesn't need to care about them.

> use all your css , fonts, and custom js files from asset pipeline

Before we had `sprockets` and `webpacker`, two asset piplines that did the same thing. Two asset urls `/assets` and `/packs`, two compilation processes, two public directories `public/assets` and `public/packs`.

In *rails 7* everything hooks into `sprockets`. Any new build tools, like `tailwindcss`, can process assets and put them in `app/assets/builds` where sprockets can do what it did before - compile and serve in development, precompile for production.

Comment: That means we should serve our css, fonts and custom js files from asset pipeline aka sprockets as it was done before webpacker was introduced. Only if we want to load any external javascript library like jquery, then we should do that kind of stuff using importmaps. Am I right in my observation??

Comment: @MuhammadAns you can use importmaps for your local javascript files. i've linked my answer on how to do that in your previous question.